# Trimmer Capacitor for TX Crystal Oscillator / RF

Tags: rf, pcb-design

I'm building a 433.92MHz transmitter.

I have gone through some revisions, and have been hand tuning the transmitters.

I settled on two 1pF caps, and that has been working for sample units.

I got our pre-production batch of 10 boards, and we noticed a few of the transmitters are not well tuned.  Typically a modification of +/- 0.5pF to the tuning caps, get the oscillator back to the center frequency.

The crystal being used is ostensibly 10PPM, and honestly theoretically should work up to 100PPM if you do the math based on the stated permitted frequency deviation of the receiver.  I however, do not have the luxury of math -- because the 10PPM crystals I have, are not performing like they should when you start mass producing boards.

I'm thinking of adding a trimmer cap, but I'm not familiar with the underlying oscillation circuit being used in our transmitter IC.  I think it's a parallel resonant circuit, as the caps are parallel to the trimmer cap.

If the two caps are in parallel, the total capacitance to the crystal is one half of each?

Based on the schematic below, I'm thinking I could get rid of the two load caps, and just add one trimmer in place of the cap?[image].

I need in a range of 0.5pF to 4pF, in the trimmer cap so that is why I am thinking of getting rid of the other 1pF cap.  Maybe I replace the 1pF with a 0.5pF?  Does it really matter?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70284/discussion-on-question-by-leroy105-trimmer-capacitor-for-tx-crystal-oscillator).

Comment: What is component U1?

Comment: @Andyaka -- sent you an email to @ jamesoakwood